# iOS background fetch fails when device battery is below 40%

Tags: ios, batterylevel, background-fetch

We recently found that even though Low-battery mode is enabled or disabled, the background fetch fails when the device battery level is low.

We haven't figure out what is the exact battery level it does support, as some of our test devices fail with battery level being below 28%, and some even fail at 39%.

The only test case we did not reproduce is, the fetch didn't fail at 40% and above.

> we aren't worried about Low-power mode as it will suspend the
>   background fetch in the app.

If the device is connected to charging, then in case of Low-power mode the fetch works only at 40% and above.

My question is should I consider the minimum battery level should be 40%  or some X % and how to determine this X ?

With large data sets, the sync time could be upto 2hrs. If we could know the proper battery level needed to make background fetch works, then we could design our app accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Is your app doing heavy tasks when executing `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:`? Remember that your code in that method should be very efficient and low time consuming (Also you always have to call the completionHandler). As [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/preparing_your_app_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh?language=objc) says:

> Calling the completion handler in a timely manner, and with an
>   accurate result, helps determine how much future execution time your
>   app receives. If you take too long to update your app, the system may
>   schedule your app less frequently in the future to save power.

If your code inside the `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:` executes heavy tasks the SO will reduce the priority of your app when calling for a background fetch. I suggest you to review your code and look for lines of codes that can be optimized.